# Scaling anchor tag in CSS

Tags: html, css, anchor

Hi guys I cannot scale my anchor tag on hover, this is my code :

```css
a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.5s;

}

a:hover{
  color:blue;
  transform:scale(3);
}
```

```html
<a>TEST</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

transforms dont work on **non replaced** `inline` element , so you can just give `display: inline-block`

```css
  a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    display: inline-block;
}

a:hover{
  color:blue;
  transform:scale(3);
}
```

```html
<a>TEST</a>
```

refer here 
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#terminology